# How should I compare 2 tensorflow models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, tf.keras

I have trained models in TensorFlow on 2 different but similar datasets, each using the same code as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(D,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')                                    
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

r = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=120)
```

The datasets are financial time series, so I don't think it makes sense to combine them. I would like to see how similar the resulting models are after training, to decide if it would make sense to use one general model for both datasets.

First off, what should I be looking at to determine model similarity? The layer weights?

Second, how can I get this info from my trained models so that I can visualize it?

Comment: What's so different about the 2 datasets?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Both are financial data, but from 2 different financial assets

Comment: Sorry @Riley Bolon. I don't know enough about time series data to comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

my answer will be very general as there is some missing information in order to provide an accurate answer to your question.

First of all- regarding comparing the weights. There is a built-in function in Keras which allows you to retrieve the weights from a certain layer on your model.
layer.get_weights() #returns the weights of the layer as a list of Numpy arrays.

But more specific to your model. I can see you are basically performing a logistic regression on your data in order to solve a classification problem. There are many aspects which allows you to compare two different models, yet in this case, you are basically applying a mathematical method on two different datasets. Therefore, by build, your weights to each dataset will be different. The comparison between the two cases wouldn't give you any real insights on your model's ability to generalize. The dataset which contains less 'noise' will make the logistic regression perform better - and that's pretty much all that you can say about it.

As long as you stick to basic techniques such as logit models, I'd recommend to check the package ['statsmodels'](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit). this package performs those kinds of regressions based on statistical (like, for linear regression -> OLS) methods instead of the gradient descent method which might not be the optimal solution in this case.

Everything I wrote is very theoretical and general and might not be a perfect fit for your needs and your dataset, yet I believe it may help you with the question you presented.
Feel free to ask more questions and provide some more specific details about your problem!

UPDATE:
What would you like to see in your visualizations?
The regression itself? The loss as a function of the epochs? the coefficients for your features?

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am using the same features as inputs for both datasets, and I would like to know if the features have roughly similar impacts on the predictions my model makes. For example, because I am working with futures contracts, I believe there could be a relationship between the number of days until the contract expires and the price of the contract. So in this case I would like to know if the impact of DaysBeforeExpiry on the prediction is consistent across both datasets. And so on, for all of my features.

Comment: Seems like you are dealing with an oil-like industry. What exactly do you try to predict? It seems like applying simple linear regression as either classic OLS model or as a probit model would help you a lot. Unlike other machine learning algorithms, Linear Regression is easy to interpret. You can calculate the coefficient for each feature and see if it is statistically significant (if it's impact on the Y variable is beyond any doubt). Let me know what you are trying to predict and I'll help you out figuring out what is the perfect solution to your problem.

Comment: My Y variable is either 0 or 1, representing if the change in the difference between 2 correlated prices on the next day is greater than 0.5% in a certain direction. This is an event that I believe would result in a profitable trade, so I am trying to predict when it will happen.

Comment: I see, In order to receive some more information about the impact of your variables over your Y variable you should definitely use a probit model. a probit model is essentially a linear regression that outputs the probability of an event to happen. Even if the model performs poorly, You can still know that way what's going on exactly inside your logistic regression as logit models are basically a sigmoid transformation of linear models. The best tools to do so are either with the 'statsmodels' package I mentioned earlier or with another programming language named R.

Comment: In general, R is very recommended for financial analysis. I can guide you with either one of the options if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

As the datasets are both similar, I assume you can make a validation set combining samples from both of the datasets. then see if the validation loss is closer.

Comment: The thing is that I am using time series data for 2 different financial assets, so i'm not sure if I can combine the 2 datasets in a way that would make sense.

Comment: sorry, I don't know much about time series data.

Answer (score 0):

If both dataset are similar, maybe you could split both sets into training and evaluation subsets and, after training use evaluation sets to calculate some metrics and compare them between the two models.